# JavaScript ModalPopups - Replace OK button with custom button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, ajax

I have the following ModalPopups. I want the default OK button and the footer section to be hidden. How do we achieve it?

Also, how do I reduce the height of the header? Is these values documented anywhere?

```
 function ModalPopupShow() {

        IsPopShow = 1;
        ModalPopups.Alert("SessionExpirePopUp",

           "<div class='warning-title-bar'>"+
            " <h3>Warning Screen</h3>" +
           "</div>",

    "<div style='padding:25px;'>Your session will expire within 5 minutes...<br/></div>"+
     "<div style='text-align: right'> <input id='btnSessionOk' value='OK' type='button' /> </div>",

    {
        width: 700,   
        titleBackColor: "#d4e1f3",
        titleFontColor: "#FF0000",
        popupBackColor: "#f3f8ff",
        popupFontColor: "black",
    }
);
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: One solution is using ModalPopups.Indicator. Still how to control the height of the header?

Comment: Can you explain how and where to override the style?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried display: none or visibility: hidden as a style for the button.

Comment: Where can we change it? In style file? Can you please provide sample code?